# Multiple wildcard preg_match_all php

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

I want to extract a number from html, between `<td>...</td>`. I have tryed to following code:

```
$views = "/<td id=\"adv-result-views-(?:.*)\" class=\"spec\">(.*?)<\/td>/";
```

after -views- is a random number. What is the right code for ignoring the random number in the search?

Comment: Can you post an example of the html you want to match ?

Comment: `<td id="adv-result-views-190147977" class="spec">
4
</td>`

The number 4 is what I would like to get with the preg_match_all

Comment: `adv-result-views-\d+`

Comment: @PedroLobito, Stop advertizing your answer. OP will get notification when you posted once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `DOM` will be the right way..

Proceed this way...

```
<?php
$htm = '<td id="adv-result-views-190147977" class="spec"> 4 </td>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($htm);
echo $content = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue; //4
```

Comment: it's not the numbers i would like to extract but the "Sometext" in your example. And a DOM is not possible since the class is used in multiple <td>'s and the id is random.

Comment: I don't think you fully understood the question.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran is correct in his approach of using the DOM

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = '<td id="adv-result-views-190147977" class="spec"> 4 </td>';

// get the value of element
echo trim( strip_tags( $html ) );

// get the number in id attribute, replace string with group capture $1
echo preg_replace( '/^.*?id="[\pLl-]+(\d+).*$/s', '$1', $html );   
/*
    ^.*?id="            Any character from the beginning of string, not gready
        id="            Find 'id="'
            [\pLl-]+    Lower case letter and '-' ( 1 or more times )
            (\d+)       Group and capture to \1 -> digits (0-9) (1 or more times) -> end of \1                      
    .*$                 Any character, gready, until end of the string
*/

// get html withut the number in id attribute
echo preg_replace( '/(^.*?id="[\pLl-]+)(\d+)(.*$)/s', '$1$3', $html );
```

This is a regex example since the question is tagged as such, but [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is 
the preferred way ( especially in SO community ) for parsing html.